# Run script on pipeline output variable number of times

Tags: bash, pipeline

I have a command that appends a computed column to stdout that I would like to apply a variable `N` number of times.

For example if my input was 'hello\nworld\n' and I wanted to append a column of 0, `N=3` times I could type the following:

```
echo -e 'hello\nworld' | sed 's/$/ 0/' | sed 's/$/ 0/' | sed 's/$/ 0/'
```

I've been trying stupid ideas like:

```
echo -e 'hello\nworld' | (for i in $(seq 1 $N); do echo $(cat) 0; done)
```

and

```
echo -e 'hello\nworld' | (for i in $(seq 1 $N); do sed 's/$/ 0/'; done)
```

but clearly these are not chaining the pipeline.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with recursion:

```
repeat() {
  count="$1"
  shift
  if [ "$count" -ge 1 ]
  then
    "$@" | repeat "$((count-1))" "$@"
  else
    cat
  fi
}
```

Examples:

```
$ echo foo | repeat 0 sed 's/$/ 0/'
foo
$ echo foo | repeat 1 sed 's/$/ 0/'
foo 0
$ echo foo | repeat 3 sed 's/$/ 0/'
foo 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to append a value of `0` a multiple N = 3 times:

```
awk -v value="0" -v N=3 \
    '{printf "%s", $0; for (i = 0; i < N; i++) printf " %s", value; print "" }'
```

Pass the value and the repeat count as variables to `awk`.  For each line, print the input; then add N copies of the value; then emit a newline.

You could use OFS (the output field separator) in place of blanks to separate the output in the loop:

```
printf "%s%s", OFS, value;
```